# Adobe Illustrator Find Layer by Name Using JavaScript

Tags: illustrator-scripting

I have been looking into the scripting side of Illustrator and have been struggling to get my head around things.

I am trying to create a simple code that would find a layer by name/ID and change its content.

I can create a code to create a new layer, but I am struggling to modify this to allow me to change a layer that already exists.

Any help is greatly appreciated.